# Extract infromation from textfile and generate output csv table with python

Tags: python, csv, text, gps

I guess i have quite a complex Question:

I extractet some metadata from pictures in a Folder with an EXIF extractor. It generated a txt file for each picture with metadata. Now im looking for a procedure to extract only some information (GPS Data) of all the txt files and generate a csv table with it. I think Python would be great for solving the problem, but it's not really my strength..

The txt files with the metadata for each picture looks like this:

> ---- ExifTool ----
>
> ExifTool Version Number         : 11.23
>
> Warning                         : [minor] Unrecognized MakerNotes
>
> ---- System ----
>
> File Name                       : GOPR0118.jpg
>
> Directory                       : Z:/myDirectory
>
> File Size                       : 4.3 MB
>
> File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:12:27 15:20:37+01:00
>
> File Access Date/Time           : 2018:12:29 18:33:59+01:00
>
> File Creation Date/Time         : 2018:12:28 16:41:25+01:00
>
> File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
>
> ---- File ----
>
> File Type                       : JPEG
>
> File Type Extension             : jpg
>
> MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
>
> Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
>
> Image Width                     : 4000
>
> Image Height                    : 3000
>
> Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
>
> Bits Per Sample                 : 8
>
> Color Components                : 3
>
> Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
>
> ---- IFD0 ----
>
> Image Description               : DCIM\100GOPRO\GOPR0118.JPG
>
> Make                            : GoPro
>
> Camera Model Name               : HERO7 Black
>
> Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
>
> X Resolution                    : 72
>
> Y Resolution                    : 72
>
> Resolution Unit                 : inches
>
> Software                        : HD7.01.01.61.00
>
> Modify Date                     : 2018:12:27 15:20:37
>
> Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
>
> ---- ExifIFD ----
>
> Exposure Time                   : 1/581
>
> F Number                        : 2.8
>
> Exposure Program                : Program AE
>
> ISO                             : 100
>
> Exif Version                    : 0221
>
> Date/Time Original              : 2018:12:27 15:20:37
>
> Create Date                     : 2018:12:27 15:20:37
>
> Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
>
> Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 0.003367003367
>
> Shutter Speed Value             : 1/512
>
> Aperture Value                  : 2.8
>
> Exposure Compensation           : 0
>
> Max Aperture Value              : 2.8
>
> Subject Distance                : 0 m
>
> Metering Mode                   : Average
>
> Light Source                    : Unknown
>
> Flash                           : No flash function
>
> Focal Length                    : 3.0 mm
>
> Flashpix Version                : ....
>
> Color Space                     : Unknown (0)
>
> Exif Image Width                : 4000
>
> Exif Image Height               : 3000
>
> Exposure Index                  : 2147483595
>
> Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
>
> File Source                     : Digital Camera
>
> Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
>
> Custom Rendered                 : Normal
>
> Exposure Mode                   : Auto
>
> White Balance                   : Auto
>
> Digital Zoom Ratio              : 1
>
> Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 15 mm
>
> Scene Capture Type              : Landscape
>
> Gain Control                    : None
>
> Contrast                        : Normal
>
> Saturation                      : Normal
>
> Sharpness                       : Hard
>
> Device Setting Description      : (Binary data 4 bytes, use -b option
>   to  extract)
>
> Subject Distance Range          : Unknown
>
> Serial Number                   : C3281324633583
>
> ---- InteropIFD ----
>
> Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
>
> Interoperability Version        : 0100
>
> ---- GPS ----
>
> GPS Latitude Ref                : North
>
> GPS Latitude                    : 47 deg 32' 5.08"
>
> GPS Longitude Ref               : East
>
> GPS Longitude                   : 7 deg 38' 30.49"
>
> GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
>
> GPS Altitude                    : 391.343 m
>
> GPS Time Stamp                  : 14:20:36
>
> GPS Date Stamp                  : 2018:12:27
>
> ---- IFD1 ----
>
> Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
>
> X Resolution                    : 72
>
> Y Resolution                    : 72
>
> Resolution Unit                 : inches
>
> Thumbnail Offset                : 44032
>
> Thumbnail Length                : 17046
>
> Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 17046 bytes, use -b
>   option to  extract)
>
> ---- MPF0 ----
>
> MPF Version                     : 0100
>
> Number Of Images                : 2
>
> Image UID List                  : (Binary data 66 bytes, use -b option
>   to  extract)
>
> Total Frames                    : 1
>
> ---- MPImage1 ----
>
> MP Image Flags                  : Representative image, Dependent
>   parent image
>
> MP Image Format                 : JPEG
>
> MP Image Type                   : Baseline MP Primary Image
>
> MP Image Length                 : 4270517
>
> MP Image Start                  : 0
>
> Dependent Image 1 Entry Number  : 2
>
> Dependent Image 2 Entry Number  : 0
>
> ---- MPImage2 ----
>
> MP Image Flags                  : Dependent child image
>
> MP Image Format                 : JPEG
>
> MP Image Type                   : Large Thumbnail (VGA equivalent)
>
> MP Image Length                 : 279747
>
> MP Image Start                  : 4270517
>
> Dependent Image 1 Entry Number  : 0
>
> Dependent Image 2 Entry Number  : 0
>
> Preview Image                   : (Binary data 279747 bytes, use -b
>   option to  extract)
>
> ---- GoPro ----
>
> Device ID                       : 1
>
> Device Name                     : Photo Global Settings
>
> Firmware Version                : HD7.01.01.61.00
>
> GoPro LINF                      : LAJ8052335601085
>
> GoPro CINF                      : 205 66 180 5 244 37 205 102 27 201
>   50 195 54  92 97 236
>
> Camera Serial Number            : C3281324633583
>
> Camera Model Name               : HERO7 Black
>
> GoPro MUID                      : 95699661 1724720628 3274885403
>   3965803574 0 0  0 0
>
> GoPro CMOD                      : 17
>
> GoPro MTYP                      : 11
>
> Auto Rotation                   : Up
>
> Digital Zoom                    : Yes
>
> GoPro DZST                      : 0
>
> GoPro SMTR                      : N
>
> Pro Tune                        : Off
>
> White Balance                   :
>
> Sharpness                       :
>
> Color Mode                      :
>
> GoPro EXPT                      : AUTO
>
> Auto ISO Max                    : 0
>
> Auto ISO Min                    : 0
>
> Exposure Compensation           :
>
> Rate                            : 4_1SEC
>
> Photo Resolution                : 12MP_W
>
> HDR Setting                     : OFF
>
> GoPro PRAW                      : N
>
> GoPro HFLG                      : 0
>
> ---- Composite ----
>
> Aperture                        : 2.8
>
> GPS Altitude                    : 391.3 m Above Sea Level
>
> GPS Date/Time                   : 2018:12:27 14:20:36Z
>
> GPS Latitude                    : 47 deg 32' 5.08" N
>
> GPS Longitude                   : 7 deg 38' 30.49" E
>
> GPS Position                    : 47 deg 32' 5.08" N, 7 deg 38' 30.49"
>   E
>
> Image Size                      : 4000x3000
>
> Megapixels                      : 12.0
>
> Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 5.0
>
> Shutter Speed                   : 1/581
>
> Circle Of Confusion             : 0.006 mm
>
> Field Of View                   : 100.4 deg
>
> Focal Length                    : 3.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 15.0 mm)
>
> Hyperfocal Distance             : 0.53 m
>
> Light Value                     : 12.2

The csv template should contain the filename and the GPS Data and be diplayed like this:

```
|---------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
|      filename       |     lat              | long               |
|---------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
|    GOPR0118.jpg     | 47 deg 32' 5.08" N   |7 deg 38' 30.49" E  |
|---------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
```

Any Help is much appreciated!

Cheers
Fabi

Comment: It would be much easier to use a Python EXIF library and access the information directly. It would then be very straightforward to write the CSV file directly.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: Thanks for your Reply. I know how this must seem that i want to let others do my work. I'm a total noob at Python and i did some research and tried some codes but they didn't work, so i thought i'd just put a detailed overview of my problem in here instead of putting some codes that don't work at all.

Comment: @Martin Evans: Thanks for the input, i didn't realise there was such a solution. Thank you very much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I managed to put a little code together that does the trick. In case someone needs to solve the same or a similar problem:

```
import os

folder = "C:\\yourPath"

files = os.listdir(folder)

print(files)

forcsv = []

for i in files:
    #print(i[-3:])
    if i[-3:] == "txt":
        gps = [i]
        file = open(folder + "\\" + i)
        for line in file:
            l = line.split(":")
            if l[0][:3] == "GPS":
                gps.append(l[1].replace("\n",""))

    forcsv.append(gps)
    file.close()

for i in forcsv:
    print(i)

file = open(folder + "\\" + "output.csv", "w")

head = "Name;North;East;AboveSeaLevel;Datetime" + "\n"
file.write(head)
for i in forcsv:
    string = i[0] + ";" + i[2] + ";" + i[4] + ";" + i[6] + ";" + i[10] + "\n"
    file.write(string)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, instead of trying to parse the text output from the exif tool you used you could solve the entire pipeline using Python and the `PIL` library.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import GPSTAGS

def get_exif(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.verify()
    return image._getexif()

def get_geotagging(exif):
    if not exif:
        raise ValueError("No EXIF metadata found")

    geotagging = {}
    for (idx, tag) in TAGS.items():
        if tag == 'GPSInfo':
            if idx not in exif:
                raise ValueError("No EXIF geotagging found")

            for (key, val) in GPSTAGS.items():
                if key in exif[idx]:
                    geotagging[val] = exif[idx][key]

    return geotagging
```

With that it's just using Python to iterate over the images instead of text files and writing out your CSV file.  Might be a little cleaner than trying to parse the text and would give you some flexibility in you wanted to use decimal lat, long instead of degrees, minutes, and seconds.

A little more detail for working with Exif including converting the latitude and longitude to decimal can be found in this blog post: [Getting Started with Geocoding Exif Image Metadata in Python 3](https://developer.here.com/blog/getting-started-with-geocoding-exif-image-metadata-in-python3)